# Faster way to add object to NSMutableArray from URL

Tags: objective-c, ios8, nsmutablearray, uipickerview, nsmutabledictionary

> I am Working on an app where user have to select hometown and country
>   for signup. For this, I' m getting country list and cities list from
>   `URL`, adding in `NSMutableArray` and populating in `UIPickerView`. Now, the
>   issue is When I call method for getting country list,it takes 5-6
>   seconds to load.Then,I have to call the method for getting cities list
>   corresponding to country name. But, the count of cities is more.So, it
>   takes long time to add cities name in array. Here is my code to get
>   cities list.

```
 NSString *urlString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/selected_city",BaseURL];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request=[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    NSString *postData=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"country_name=%@",self.countryField.text];
    [request setHTTPBody:[postData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    NSLog(@"posted data is %@",postData);
    [request setValue:@"binary"
   forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Transfer-Encoding"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
   forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [self loadCountryList];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                       queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError)
     {

         if(data)
         {
             NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
             NSDictionary* responseDict = [NSJSONSerialization
                                           JSONObjectWithData:data
                                           options:kNilOptions
                                           error:&error];

             NSString *responseStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
             NSLog(@"%@",responseStr);
             if ([[responseDict valueForKey:@"message"] isEqualToString:@"Request Successfull"])
             {
                   NSArray *predictArr = [responseDict objectForKey:@"city_list"];
                 dispatch_queue_t q = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
                 dispatch_async(q, ^{
                     /* Fetch the image from the server... */
                     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                         for(int i=0;i<[predictArr count];i++)
                         {
                             NSMutableDictionary *data=[[predictArr objectAtIndex:i] mutableCopy];

                               [cityArray addObject:data];
                             NSLog(@"countries array is %@",cityArray);
                         }
                         [self stopLoading];
                         [cityPicker reloadAllComponents];

                     });
                    });
            }
             else
             {
                 [self stopLoading];
             }
         }
         else
         {
             [self stopLoading];
         }
     }];
```

> So, if there's any faster way to add object in `NSMutableArray` and
>   Populate `UIPickerView`. Any help would  be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have you profiled it (with Instruments) to see what part is really slowing it down?  Network connection or code?  Also, if you're talking about a really large array, `NSLog` alone will slow you down quite a bit

Comment: @jn_pdx, Thanks man. It worked.It was not connection problem. Removing NSLog made it faster.

Comment: @Sushil If you want logging without the performance hit, try CocoaLumberjack for asynchronous logging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As referenced in my comment above, `NSLog` will be a significant use of time given a big enough list.  Removing it from your loop will speed things up considerably.